# Sending Android SMS Gets Stuck In Status Sending

Tags: java, android, sms, android-pendingintent

I am using a content resolver to send text messages within Android:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(6);
... 
values.put("status", 0);

...
Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox"), values);
```

This works great as it shows up in the text message app. It successfully sends **AND** a delivery report of successful is received in return, yet it stays in Sending state.

Any idea why or some pointers on how to update?

Comment: Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: All my messages that are stuck sending keep saying message failed every 10 minutes in the notification bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I queried the outbox messages with this content resolver:

```
Cursor outboxCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox"), null, null, null, null);
```

Then deleted them with:

```
Uri deleteURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox/");
context.getContentResolver().delete(deleteURI, null, null);
```